Script Freezes in Seleniumbase
When I run the .exe of my script (based on Seleniumbase framework), after some time (about 60 minutes), the script stops unexpectedly. The script opens 3 tabs with 3 links and switches between tabs to check if a specific element is present on the webpage, with a timeout of 0.1 seconds: sb.assert_element_present("//li[@class='onsale but']//div[contains(text(),'32,80 €')]",timeout=0.1)
What could be causing the script to freeze after a while? Could it be that switching tabs too quickly is causing the issue? How can I optimize the code?
Here is the complete code:
with SB(is_mobile=True,headless2=False,user_data_dir=user_data_dir,chromium_arg=chromium_arg) as sb:
    sb.driver.maximize_window()
    for url in urls:

        sb.execute_script(f"window.open('{url}');")
    
    time.sleep(1)

    ventanas = sb.driver.window_handles

    lista_buenas = []
    while True:
    
        if len(lista_buenas) == len(urls):
        
            break

        for x in range(1,len(ventanas)):
        
            if x not in lista_buenas:
                sb.switch_to_window(sb.driver.window_handles[x])
                try:
                    sb.driver.switch_to_frame("iframe[sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms']")
                    sb.refresh()
                except:
                    nombrito = sb.get_text("//header[@data-pw-test-id='event-header']//h1/span")
                    print(f"(+) Todo bien en {nombrito}")
                    lista_buenas.append(x)
            else:
                continue

    sb.switch_to_window(sb.driver.window_handles[0])
    sb.driver.close()
    time.sleep(1)
    nuevas = sb.driver.window_handles
    
    #this is the main code
    while True:
        try:
            for x in range(len(nuevas)):
                
                sb.switch_to_window(nuevas[x])
                
                nombre_evento = sb.get_text("//header[@data-pw-test-id='event-header']//h1/span")
                sb.click("//button[@data-button-tracking-id='toggle-tickets-modal-open']",scroll=False)
    
                try:
                    sb.switch_to_frame("//iframe[@id='#tickets-iframe-s']")
            
                except:
                    print("(-) HA TARDADO EN CARGAR...")
                    pass    

                try:
                
                    sb.assert_element_present("//li[@class='onsale but']//div[contains(text(),'32,80 €')]",timeout=0.1)
                    mensaje = f"Entrada encontrada para el evento: {nombre_evento}"
                    telegram(mensaje)

        
                    sb.switch_to_default_content()
                    sb.click('//button[@data-button-tracking-id="toggle-tickets-modal-closed"]')
                    
                except:
                    sb.switch_to_default_content()
                    sb.click('//button[@data-button-tracking-id="toggle-tickets-modal-closed"]')
                    continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Saliendo...")
            break
    
sb.driver.quit()

I ran a script that opens 3 tabs, checks for a specific element on each webpage, and switches between tabs to verify the presence of the element. I expected the script to run continuously without issues. However, after about 60 minutes, the script unexpectedly stops or freezes.
